# Auto-Return to my web application After Payment

Tags: asp.net

I am using Minicart plugin in asp.net for paypal.
I have set auto return URL. when I click on payNow button it is suppose to take me to my web application, but it stays on this page and I get one link. Clicking on that link it takes to my web application.

Could you please tell me how automatically it will redirect to my web application without clicking any link.